# C2259 error (directx 11)

Tags: c++, directx

I am using Beginning DirectX 11 Game Programming by Allen Sherrod, Wendy Jones book and I am having trouble with following code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <memory>
#include "BlankDemo.h"

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, 
                    WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE prevInstance,
         LPWSTR cmdLine, int cmdShow)
{
UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(prevInstance);
UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(cmdLine);

WNDCLASSEX wndClass = {0};
wndClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wndClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
wndClass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
wndClass.hInstance = hInstance;
wndClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wndClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
wndClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
wndClass.lpszClassName = "DX11BookWindowClass";

if(!RegisterClassEx (&wndClass))
    return -1;

RECT rc = {0, 0, 640, 480};
AdjustWindowRect(&rc, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, FALSE);

HWND hwnd = CreateWindowA("DX11BookWindowClass","BlankWin32Window",WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, rc.right - rc.left,
    rc.bottom - rc.top, NULL,NULL,hInstance,NULL);

if(!hwnd)
    return -1;
ShowWindow(hwnd,cmdShow);

BlankDemo* demo = new BlankDemo();

bool result = demo->Initialize(hInstance, hwnd);

if(result == false)
    return -1;

MSG msg = {0};

while(msg.message != WM_QUIT)
{
    if(PeekMessage(&msg,0,0,0,PM_REMOVE))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    else
    {
        demo->Update(0.0f);
        demo->Render();
    }
}

demo->Shutdown();

return static_cast<int>(msg.wParam);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, 
                    WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
PAINTSTRUCT paintStruct;
HDC hDC;

switch(message)
{
case WM_PAINT:
    hDC = BeginPaint(hwnd, &paintStruct);
    EndPaint(hwnd, &paintStruct);
    break;

case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;

default:
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
return 0;
}
```

I get IntelliSense: object of abstract class type "BlankDemo" is not allowed error. class declaration:

```
#ifndef _BLANK_DEMO_H_
#define _BLANK_DEMO_H_

#include "DemoBase.h"

class BlankDemo : public Dx11DemoBase
{
public:
BlankDemo();
virtual ~BlankDemo();

bool LoadContent();
void UnloadContent();

void Upadate(float dt);
void Render();
};

#endif
```

Comment: I am not sure what `Dx11DemoBase` is, but it has abstract parts that you didn't override.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misspelled one of your functions.

```
void Upadate(float dt);
```

should be

```
void Update(float dt);
```

Typos like these were a common mistake in earlier versions of C++.  If you are compiling C++11, you can have the compiler verify your intentions with:

```
void Update(float dt) override;
```

Comment: thx i lost 2 hours on resolving this :)